# Set a gradient to an inline SVG with jQuery SVG plugin

Tags: jquery, svg, gradient

how can i load this svg and set the gradient with the [jQuery SVG Plugin](http://keith-wood.name/svg.html)?

```
<div id="test">
    <svg style="transform: none; backface-visibility: hidden; transform-origin: 50% 50% 0px; cursor: move;" width="100%" height="100%" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
         <g>
         <path d="M32,2.47c-14.027,0-25.44,10.357-25.44,23.088c0,7.572,4.092,14.662,10.95,18.979c0.255,7.662-2.309,14.418-2.419,14.699 l-0.899,2.295l18.509-12.899c13.647-0.34,24.74-10.677,24.74-23.073C57.44,12.827,46.028,2.47,32,2.47z">
        </path>
         </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

This doest not work, but why?

```
var svg = $('#test svg').svg('get');                  
svg.linearGradient( $('#test svg'), 
                    'MyGradient', 
                    [ ['5%', '#F60'], ['95%', '#FF6']] );
```

Error:

```
TypeError: svg is undefined
```

i included all js files correctly

```
jquery.js
jquery-ui.js 
jquery.svg.js
jquery.svgfilter.js
```

**UPDATE**
Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Ltbgcfb8/

**DOCS**
http://keith-wood.name/svgRef.html#svgparams

```
$(selector).svg({loadURL: '', onLoad: fn, settings: {}, initPath: ''})
```

Attach an SVG canvas to the specified division or inline SVG element.

**loadURL** (string, optional) is the URL of the initial document to load.

**onLoad** (function, optional) is a callback functional invoked following loading. It receives a reference to the SVG Wrapper object as a parameter. this refers to the containing division.

**settings** (object, optional) is the new settings to use for this SVG instance.

**initPath** (string, optional) is any additional path to the blank.svg file.

```
Since 1.1.0 - previously you used $(selector).svg(url, onLoad, settings);.
Since 1.2.0 - initPath setting and onLoad receives parameter of SVG Wrapper object.
Since 1.4.3 - allow target object to be inline SVG.
```

Comment: Please create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Are you making sure to run your code after the DOM is ready?

Comment: yes, the code runs after the dom is ready.
I created a jsfiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/Ltbgcfb8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it

```
$('#test svg').svg(); 
var svg = $('#test svg').svg('get'); 
svg.add($('#test svg > *'));
```

Answer (score -1):

I update your JsFiddle for you.
You must use :

```
<defs>
      <linearGradient id="Gradient" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="1">
         <stop offset="5%" stop-color="#F60"/>
        <stop offset="95%" stop-color="#FF6" stop-opacity="0"/>
      </linearGradient>
  </defs>
```

see here https://jsfiddle.net/Ltbgcfb8/1/.

Hope that helps